# WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT id... Only sometimes it does exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. I want to select an Id from one table where a row does not exist in another table based on a date...  Only I can't seem to find the correct row in the second table

Table 1

```
adId    info        tableX      tableY
1       blah, blah     Y          N
2       blah, blah     N          Y
3       blah, blah     N          N
4       blah, blah     N          Y
5       blah, blah     N          Y
```

Table 2

```
id      start_date  unitId      adId
1       2014-04-01    1          1
2       2014-03-02    2          1
3       2014-04-01    2          2
4       2014-03-01    0          4
```

The relationship of the unitID in Table2 comes from two tables X and Y (I'm not sure if its relevant but I'll describe it in case it is)

TableX

```
unitId    adid
1          1
2          1
```

TableY

```
unitId    adId
1           5
2           2
3           4
```

I want to select adId=1, adId=3,  adId=5,  from Table 1 as in Table 2, none of them have a date in March  (NB adId=2 and 5 does not appear in Table 2 at all)

This will find adId= 2 and 5 but not 1.

```
When I do SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Table1.adId
FROM Table1
WHERE (NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT id, start_date
     FROM Table2
         WHERE (Table1.adId = adId) AND (Table2.start_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01'AND '2014-03-05)
    )
       )
```

How do you add a clause so that its looking for DISTINCT on adId and UnitID?

Is DISTINCT the best way to approach this or is there another way?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect to get 1 with such a query: ad 1 has an entry between 1st and 5th of March in your data. I guess I didn't fully understand your requirements (and I'm not quite sure I understand your tables TableX and TableY or the tableX and tableY fields in Table1)

Comment: The query is just where I am up to - and does not work.  It finds the rows that are not in table two at all - but I want to build a query that will find table2.id=1 as well (table2.unitID is different)  The output I need will be  adId=1, adId=3, adId=5

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT A.* 
  FROM Table1 A
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1 
        FROM Table2 B 
       WHERE B.start_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01'AND '2014-03-05' 
         AND B.adId = A.adId )
```

Comment: This is a nice way to condense my query but it wont find adId=1 (It only finds from table 1 that are not in table 2)  The bit I'm finding hard is not selecting table2.id=1 (2014-04-01)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems over-complex. How about this one:

```
SELECT adId
FROM Table1
WHERE adId NOT IN
    (SELECT adId
     FROM Table2
     WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-05')
```

As an alternative, if you strongly oppose subqueries in the WHERE condition, you could do:

```
SELECT Table1.adId
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT adId
     FROM Table2
     WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-05') T2
     ON Table1.adId=T2.adId
WHERE T2.adId=NULL
```

Comment: Never do not use subquries in where condition.

Comment: Should that be avoid using subquries in a where condition

Comment: @Hett - This type of blanket statement might be true for some RDBMSs (e.g. MySQL) but it is not true as a general statement for SQL Server. Though actually [the preferred sub query to use would be `NOT EXISTS`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists/11074428#11074428)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the MINUS set operator:

```
select adId
  from table1
 where start_date not between '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-05'
minus
select adId
  from table1
 where start_date between '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-05'
```